# Issue upgrading Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise from 17.7.7 to 17.8.1

Tags: visual-studio-2022, .net-8.0

I'm currently facing an issue while trying to upgrade Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise edition from version 17.7.7 to 17.8.1. I followed the standard upgrade process using the VS Installer.

- Visual Studio version before upgrade: 17.7.7
- Visual Studio version after upgrade attempt: 17.8.1
- Operating system: Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise

[image]

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Can anyone please help me here by providing their guidance

Comment: You can find log and fix it yourself. You can try ask Microsoft but this is usualy without success unless you are very rich customer. At last you can uninstall it and install it again which is usualy easiest and fastest way for fixing such issues.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue by opening VS Installer in Administrator mode. Post that I was able to see .NET 8 (Long Term Support) target framework

Comment: This worked for me too.

Answer (score -2):

In the Visual Studio Installer,look for the installation of VisualStudio that you want to update.
if it is  showing something went wrong try again by reconnecting the network